# Cannot access the actual value of a Javascript array of constructed objects - returns undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I have created an array of objects of the form

```
const objectOne = {
    name: 'NameOne',
    data: [{x: 'dataOneX', y: 'dataOneY'},{x: 'dataTwoX', y: 'dataTwoY'}]
};
const objectTwo = {
    name: 'NameOne',
    data: [{x: 'dataOneX', y: 'dataOneY'},{x: 'dataTwoX', y: 'dataTwoY'}]
};
const newArr: [objectOne, objectTwo]
```

I then pass newArr into a component as a prop:

```
< LineChart title='title' data={newArr} />
```

Within the component, I try the following:
`console.log(data)`
and I get my array in the console. However,
`console.log(data[0].name)` returns `undefined`, and `data[0]` returns the name of the original object I passed in. I am trying to access the data in this way so that I can test dynamically pulling from an API and passing the information into apexcharts. However, this is a hard obstacle for me - I am new to JS (and react.js which is what I am using).

Happy to clarify!

EDIT:

My actual code is:

```
 const components = [
    {
      title: 'Headcount',
      data: [{ objectOne }, { objectTwo }]
    }
 ]

<LineChart
    title="Title"
    xtype="category"
    data={components[0].data}
/>
```

And the following is what it is passed into:

```
function LineChart({ title, data }) {
  console.log(data);
  data.forEach((datum) => console.log(datum.name));
  return(
    <Box>
      <Typography>{title}</Typography>
    </Box>
  ));
}

export default LineChart;
```

The issue I am having is data.forEach((datum) => console.log(datum.name)) returns undefined but data is exactly as I expect it in the console.

Comment: As written, this `const newArr: [objectOne, objectTwo]` is invalid syntax. Please provide the details around where/how this is actually used.

Comment: edited @RandyCasburn

Comment: Do not do `data: [{ objectOne }, { objectTwo }]`. Use `data: [objectOne , objectTwo ]`. (*remove the curly brackets*). The `{ objectOne }` creates an object with a property named `objectOne` whose value is the contents of the `objectOne` variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Gabriele Petrioli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/128165/gabriele-petrioli) answered the question [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70086181/cannot-access-the-actual-value-of-a-javascript-array-of-constructed-objects-re/70086415#comment123893447_70086181):

> Do not do `data: [{ objectOne }, { objectTwo }]`. Use `data: [objectOne , objectTwo ]`. (remove the curly brackets). The `{ objectOne }` creates an object with a property named `objectOne` whose
> value is the contents of the `objectOne` variable